# Ubuntu not fully shutting down on VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu Precise (v. 12.04) on VirtualBox v. 4.1.12, on two different machines running Mac OS 10.5.8 and 10.6.8, respectively. All works as expected. I can shut down Ubuntu using the "Shut Down" command in the menu, and the guest OS does indeed shut down.

But when I try to shut down from the command line using `sudo halt`, while the guest OS does shut down, its window never disappears.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be? I have no such problem with Ubuntu Lucid (v. 10.04) in the same environments.

Comment: Wrong place to ask this question. Try [Super User](http://superuser.com/). <br/>

Stack Overflow is for asking questions that cover:<br/>
<br/>
-a specific programming problem<br/>
-a software algorithm<br/>
-software tools commonly used by programmers<br/>
-practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession.<br/>
More information: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be an open bug see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/880240
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/950129

Try `sudo shutdown -h now` instead.

Comment: Thanks. It requires a time, and I've been using `0` or `now`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable 'I/O APIC' in VirtualBox-Configuration-Sytem-Motherboard menu.

Answer (score 1):

And on most systems, 'sudo poweroff' is pretty much equivalent to 'sudo halt -p'.